# How to get static library in sdk?

Tags: sdk, static-libraries, yocto

Everyone who searched how to include a static library in SDK, surely read [this thread from 2014](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-September/021676.html). I tried what they suggested, but that didn't work.

Reading the yocto mega manual version 2.1 (yocto morty), I found in chapter 5.9.12. (Poky Reference Distribution Changes), that they added DISABLE_STATIC variable, to disable generation of static libraries. I tried adding this to my recipe, and it didn't enable adding static library to SDK:

```
DISABLE_STATIC = ""
```

I can see the library in the sysroot when building the image. But it is not getting in the SDK.

So, what exactly do I need to do to get a static library and the headers in SDK?

---

What worked is adding the staticdev package to ´IMAGE_INSTALL´ in `local.conf`, but I don't want to have to do that.

---

I created an example recipe, which demonstrates my problem. The directory structure is like this:

```
example-staticlib/
example-staticlib/example-staticlib_0.1.bb
example-staticlib/files/
example-staticlib/files/lib.c
example-staticlib/files/lib.h
example-staticlib/files/Makefile
```

example-staticlib_0.1.bb :

```
DESCRIPTION = "example stared library"
LICENSE = "LGPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/LGPL-2.0;md5=9427b8ccf5cf3df47c29110424c9641a"

SRC_URI = "file://lib.c \
           file://lib.h \
           file://Makefile"

PR = "r0"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"

do_install () {
    oe_runmake install DEST=${D}
}

TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "example-staticlib-dev"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "example-staticlib-staticdev"
```

lib.c:

```
int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

lib.h:

```
int foo();
```

Makefile:

```
TARGET=libexample.a

all:$(TARGET)

install :
    @install -d $(DEST)/usr/lib/
    @install -m 0644 $(TARGET) $(DEST)/usr/lib/
    @install -d $(DEST)/usr/include/
    @install -m 0644 lib.h $(DEST)/usr/include/

$(TARGET) : lib.c
    $(CC) -c lib.c -o lib.o
    $(AR) rcs $@ lib.o 

clean:
    rm -rf lib.o $(TARGET)
```

**How exactly to modify the recipe, in order to get the static library in the SDK?**

Answer (score 6):

Following your added example.

Adding the following line to your image recipe (or to an `.bbappend`, eg `core-image-minimal.bbappend`)

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "example-staticlib-staticdev"
```

should work for you. That will give you the `.a` file in the SDK, after running `bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk`. (Again assuming that the image used is `core-image-minimal`).

That your experiment to add the `.a` file to `${PN}-dev` didn't work, is duet to the order of how files are put into packages. The order is `${PN}-dbg ${PN}-staticdev ${PN}-dev ${PN}-doc ${PN}-locale ${PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN} ${PN}`. Thus, the `.a` file will, regardless, be put into `${PN}-staticdev`, as that packages is handled prior to `{PN}-dev`.

Note, you add this line, `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "example-staticlib-staticdev"` to your image recipe, thus, you need to write the package name instead of `PN`.

Comment: Yeah, remove the two lines you had. The `.a` file is automatically picked up by the `${PN}-staticdev` package.

Comment: See my added note.

Comment: See what I added to my answer before my last comment. You need to add the toolchain variable n top the image recipe.

Comment: Ok, I added an example. So how exactly to modify the recipe? I see it is possible, because other libraries (for example libarchive) are getting their static libraries in the sdk.

Comment: Ok. Only the second toolchain target task is necessary. And you need to move that line to your image recipe, eg `core-image-minimal.bb`. Ie the recipe itself can't influence what's added to the SDK nor image.

Comment: Yes, I do `bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk`, but when I execute the script in `build/tmp/deploy/sdk`, in the installed SDK, I still don't get the static library (libexample.a is nowhere to be found). The header is there, but not the library. What else can I try?

Comment: You could verify that `libexample.a` is indeed in the package `example-staticlib-staticdev`. And let us know which version you're using.

Comment: `libexample.a` is in `build/tmp/sysroot` but not in installed sdk's sysroot. What version? I use yocto morty

Comment: Well, I've just verified that it works, though it was on Krogoth. However, it should really work on Morty too.
Do you have `libexample.a` in `example-staticlib-staticdev`? Did you add a `core-image-minimal.bbappend`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a way which doesn't require editing the image recipe.

example-staticlib_0.1.bb :

After do_install. I didn't use **TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK**

FILES_${PN}-staticdev += "${libdir}/libexample.a"

RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev += "${PN}-staticdev"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"